# Making sure only a particular group of characters are in a string

Tags: python, string

Is there any way to make sure that only the characters 'm' 'c' 'b' are in a string without resorting to regex?

For instance, if the user inputs 'm', the program will print 'Major'. If the user inputs 'mc', the program will print 'Major, Critical'.

So I want to make sure that if the user inputs something like 'mca', the program will print 'Not applicable'.

```
try:
    if 'a' in args.findbugs:
        if len(args.findbugs) > 1:
            print 'findbugs: Not an applicable argument.'
        else:
            print 'FINDBUGS:ALL'
    else:
        if 'm' in args.findbugs:
            print 'FINDBUGS:MAJOR'
        if 'c' in args.findbugs:
            print 'FINDBUGS:CRITICAL'
        if 'b' in args.findbugs:
            print 'FINDBUGS:BLOCKER'
except TypeError:
    print "FINDBUGS: NONE"
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: what is args.findbugs?

Comment: args.findbugs is a String which is used as an argument for argparse.

Comment: do you want to check if the  string just contains `mc`,`m` etc.. or if those chars are in any string that is passed in like `amc`?

Comment: I want to check if the string just contains 'm', 'c', or 'b'. So 'mcb' would work whereas 'mca' would not.

Comment: what happens if `mcb` is entered?

Comment: if 'mcb' was entered, the the program would print "Major, Critical, Blocker".

Comment: so just`mcb` is acceptable? what about individual `m`,`c` or `b`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56119/discussion-between-froggy-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the simplest way from what you've described would be:

```
some_string = 'mca'
if set(some_string) <= {'m', 'c', 'b'}:
    # The string contains only 'm', 'c', or 'b'.
else:
    # The string 'mca' does not match because of 'a'.
```

Or, if you intend to require at least `m`, `c`, or `b`:

```
some_string = 'mca'
if set(some_string) & {'m', 'c', 'b'}:
    # The string contains 'm', 'c', or 'b', so 'mca' will match.
```

NOTE: As pointed out by [bgporter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203568/bgporter), the set literal notation is not available in Python versions less than 2.7. If support for those is required, use `set(('m', 'c', 'b'))`.

Comment: ...with the caveat that the `['m', 'c', 'b'}` set literal syntax isn't available in Pythons before 2.7

Comment: I find it a little overkill to use a set here, this is probably not efficient.

Comment: @user189 Not that this is really conclusive, but doing a quick timeit I got: `timeit("if all(x in l for x in s): pass", "s = 'blabla'; l = 'mcb'")` -> `0.9279`; `timeit("if set(s) <= l: pass", "s = 'blabla'; l = set('mcb')")` -> `0.6104`.

Comment: You got me there =p What about large strings?

Comment: @user189 Well with large strings, yours is much faster. Using `'blabla'*100` gives `0.9337` for yours (lazy evaluation, fails early), and `16.66` for mine (whole evaluation, not good for large input).

Answer (score 4):

This is a way to check it in linear time.

```
s = "blabla"
l = 'mcb'

print all(x in l for x in s)
```

Comment: Considering the accepted input is extremely short linear time is perfectly acceptable here. Good answer

Answer (score 1):

Crude, but this would return what you need.

```
input not in itertools.combinations('mcb', 1) + itertools.combinations('mcb', 2) + itertools.combinations('mcb', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arg_dict = {"m":'FINDBUGS:MAJOR',"c": 'FINDBUGS:CRITICAL',"b": 'FINDBUGS:BLOCKER'}

accepted =["m","c","b"]
user_args = "bccm"

if all(x in accepted for x in user_args):
    for x in set(user_args):
        print (arg_dict.get(x),
else:
    print ("FINDBUGS: NONE")

FINDBUGS:CRITICAL FINDBUGS:BLOCKER FINDBUGS:MAJOR
```

If you want them in order sort the input:

```
accepted =["m","c","b"]
user_args = "bcm"
if all(x in accepted for x in user_args):
    user_args = sorted(set(user_args),key=lambda x: accepted.index(x))
    for x in user_args:
        print "{} ".format((format(arg_dict.get(x)))),
else:
    print ("FINDBUGS: NONE")

FINDBUGS:MAJOR  FINDBUGS:CRITICAL  FINDBUGS:BLOCKER
```